# Swift Google maps Markers MapView Refresh

Tags: json, swift, xcode, google-maps

I'm getting lattitude and longitude from Api.

MapView loads just perfect, the app gets user location, and based on it, downloads markers placement on map.

But you have to wait quite a while until it downloads data, so MapView loads like 2 seconds before. How Can I resolve this? Should I somehow reload MapView?

```
func placeMarkers() {
    for i in markers {

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(i.lat, i.lng)
        marker.title = i.name
        marker.map = mapView

    }
}
```

Here is the placeMarkers function, and it's called:

```
func downloadData() {

    guard let markerUrl = URL(string: url) else {
        return
    }

    let request = URLRequest(url: markerUrl)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let data = data {
            self.markers = self.parseJSON(data: data)

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.placeMarkers()
            })
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

When the parseJSON function is done.

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887499/how-to-refresh-the-google-map-in-my-application-using-swift) hopefully will help you :)

Comment: So i added mapView with subclass of GMSMapView on IB but it's show nil on mapView :O

Comment: @Tonamini Check that outlet is connected? And where you are calling clear on mapView?

Comment: Outlet is connected. I'm calling mapView.clear () just above "for" statement in placeMarkers func.

Comment: @Tonamini Where you are getting `mapView` as `nil`?

Comment: Okay. It's quite embarrassing but i had aditional variable mapView in one function... No i'm clearing map before "for" statement and everything works! Love ya Nirav and thanks for help! <3

Comment: @Tonamini Welcome mate :)